# filtering specific key-value pairs on Hive Map column in Spark sql

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql

I have a table `TABLE1` like the following where the `feature` column includes dictionaries.

```
+---------------+----------------------------+
| column_value  |          feature           |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| A37B          | {0:"6",1:"1",2:"a",3:"x"}  |
| ACCOUNT_ID    | {0:"6",1:"2",2:"a",3:"x"}  |
| ANB_200       | {0:"6",1:"3",2:"a",3:"x"}  |
| ANB_201       | {0:"6",1:"4",2:"b",3:"y"}  |
| AS82_RE       | {0:"6",1:"5",2:"b",3:"y"}  |
| ATTR001       | {0:"7",1:"2",2:"b",3:"y"}  |
| ATTR001_RE    | {0:"7",1:"3",2:"c",3:"y"}  |
| ATTR002       | {0:"7",1:"4",2:"c",3:"z"}  |
| ATTR002_RE    | {0:"7",1:"5",2:"c",3:"z"}  |
| ATTR003       | {0:"8",1:"3",2:"d",3:"z"}  |
| ATTR004       | {0:"8",1:"4",2:"d",3:"z"}  |
| ATTR005       | {0:"8",1:"5",2:"d",3:"z"}  |
| ATTR006       | {0:"9",1:"4",2:"d",3:"z"}  |
| ATTR006       | {0:"9",1:"5",2:"d",3:"z"}  |
```

Now, I have a list of selected keys say, `[0,3]` and I want to filter out the key-value pairs of only those keys. That is the resulting table should look like following:

```
+---------------+----------------------------+
| column_value  |          feature           |
+---------------+----------------------------+
| A37B          | {0:"6",3:"x"}              |
| ACCOUNT_ID    | {0:"6",3:"x"}              |
| ANB_200       | {0:"6",3:"x"}              |
| ANB_201       | {0:"6",3:"y"}              |
| AS82_RE       | {0:"6",3:"y"}              |
| ATTR001       | {0:"7",3:"y"}              |
| ATTR001_RE    | {0:"7",3:"y"}              |
| ATTR002       | {0:"7",3:"z"}              |
| ATTR002_RE    | {0:"7",3:"z"}              |
| ATTR003       | {0:"8",3:"z"}              |
| ATTR004       | {0:"8",3:"z"}              |
| ATTR005       | {0:"8",3:"z"}              |
| ATTR006       | {0:"9",3:"z"}              |
| ATTR006       | {0:"9",3:"z"}              |
```

How can I do it in Spark sql?

Answer (score 0):

You could first remove `{` and `}`, then use `str_to_map` to create a `map` from the `string`:

```
df.withColumn("feature", regexp_replace(col("feature"), "(\\{)|(\\})", ""))
```

Then you could `map_filter` and say where `key` is `0` or `3`:

```
df.withColumn("feature", expr("map_filter(str_to_map(feature), (k, v) -> k = '0' or k ='3')"))
```

Input:

```
+------------+-------------------------+
|column_value|feature                  |
+------------+-------------------------+
|A37B        |{0:"6",1:"1",2:"a",3:"x"}|
|ACCOUNT_ID  |{0:"6",1:"2",2:"a",3:"x"}|
|ANB_200     |{0:"6",1:"3",2:"a",3:"x"}|
|ANB_201     |{0:"6",1:"4",2:"b",3:"y"}|
+------------+-------------------------+
```

Output:

```
+------------+--------------------+
|column_value|feature             |
+------------+--------------------+
|A37B        |{0 -> "6", 3 -> "x"}|
|ACCOUNT_ID  |{0 -> "6", 3 -> "x"}|
|ANB_200     |{0 -> "6", 3 -> "x"}|
|ANB_201     |{0 -> "6", 3 -> "y"}|
+------------+--------------------+
```

You can use this dataset to further operate on `map` type, you can use `to_json` finally if you want the output in your format.

Good luck!